# home and vmware lab on same subnet (AD)

Tags: networking, active-directory, esxi

I have a question about network topology. Namely, I wanted to set up a cluster vmware for testing SQL Server: fail over, always-on etc ... But I do not know how to reconcile this with your home network.

The first idea was to separate address range 2..100 - home network, virtual network 100-200. So I installed a domain controller with a fixed IP address, VMs with SQL. But when i tried to connect them to domain they were not able to find active directory server.
The problem turned out to be two servers dhcp: home and AD on the same subnet. A

After some time on google i was completely lost.. and decided to ask for help

How can I simulate the company network (AD, DHCP, DNS, etc ...) that is somehow separate but i'm able to connect from my pc to it ? avoiding conflicts.  I don't' want  to put my esxi host in charge of routing as it will be turn on very rarely only for adhoc testing.

Answer (score 2):

Don't deploy a second DHCP server.

Answer (score 1):

Although you say you don't want to put the esxi host in charge, put it in charge, use routing; IF you want to experience a second DHCP server that serves only your VM world. There're other ways to solve DHCP issues and one DHCP is always the best practice. But wanting not to mess with existing network, routing (and subnetting that means) is inevitable SINCE:

DHCP messages can not pass through a router, they're link local.